# cURL returning "Object not found!"

Tags: php, curl

I'm having problem with cURL, it's returning no result or "Object not found!"

I know the site actually provide their own API, but i need more information to be grabbed.
How to solve this problem ?

here's the code

```
<?php
        $URL = "http://myanimelist.net/manga.php?q=nisekoi";
        //Initl curl
        function get_web_page( $url )
        {
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
                CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
                CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
            );

            $ch      = curl_init( $url );
            curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
            $content = curl_exec( $ch );
            $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
            $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
            $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
            curl_close( $ch );

            $header['errno']   = $err;
            $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
            $header['content'] = $content;
            return $header;
        }
            echo get_web_page($URL)['content'];
?>
```

Comment: change the last line to: `$ar = get_web_page($URL); echo $ar['content'];`. Place `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);` at the beginning of your code. Do you get error messages?

Comment: it's giving me same result, "Object not found" sir

Comment: It returns the right data, but it loads an iframe with a relative URL to the site.

Comment: Works fine. phpinfo() and check if curl is enabled.

Comment: Also, there's a CAPTCHA. So, I'd use the API.

Comment: okay sir, i change this $header['content'] = $content; into this $header['content'] = explode("iframe",$content)[1];

now, new error given to me : 

src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=9&xinfo=4-36084509-0 0NNN RT(1405902475073 126) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1) B12(4,315,0)&incident_id=133001610148738873-228299759721712148&edet=12&cinfo=31d5180ec75381e904000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 133001610148738873-228299759721712148</

Comment: @code-addict Exactly. It's calling `/_Incapsula_Resource` relative to your server, instead of where it originated from.

Comment: aww... it's sucks.. i need to get whitelisted first to use their API, btw how they do it, i see they already use incapsula from early 2013, but i manage to get their data by file_get_contents  alone around Sept 2013 and it's still working fine til november